# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (1,)

Tags: python, matplotlib

when I try to plot f_invx I get the error in the subject.
I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Here I calculate inverse of a function

```
def calcola_funzione_inversa():

        x, y = sympy.symbols("x y") # definisce x e y come variabili simboliche
        f = Function('f')(x)        # definisce f come una funzione simbolica
        f = (2*x -3)/5

        func = sympy.Eq(y, f)        # pone y = f
        f_inv = sympy.solve(func, x) # risolve la funzione isolando x

        f_invx = f_inv[0].subs(y, x) # sostituisce x a y
        pprint(f_invx)
        return(f_invx)
```

Here I try to plot the inverse of a function

```
def disegna_funzione_inversa(f_invx):

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        x = np.linspace(-4,4,100)

        ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

        plt.plot(x, f_invx,  '-r')
        plt.show()
```

Here I call the function

```
f_inversa_in_x = calcola_funzione_inversa()
disegna_funzione_inversa(f_inversa_in_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated because your "x" in plots is a numpy.ndarray of lenght 100 and "f_invx" is singular sympy "Add" object. One easy way to mitigate this is to convert "f_inversa_in_x" to lambda function using sympy "lambdify". One implementaion may look like this:

```
def disegna_funzione_inversa(f_invx):
        # converting sympy expression to lambda funcion
        x = sympy.symbols("x")
        lambdified_f_invx = sympy.lambdify(x, f_invx) 

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        x = np.linspace(-4,4,100)

        ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

        plt.plot(x, lambdified_f_invx(x),  '-r')  # lambidified_f_inv_x is a function so we need to feed it argument
        plt.show()
```